# syntax error, unexpected identifier "define", expecting "," or ";"

Tags: php

Just started learning PHP out of curiosity. Currently going through all basic fundamentals in PHP and that's when I came across this function **define** that we do use to define variables with constant values. However, instead of showing me an expected output, it's giving me unexpected result. Can anybody help me?

```
define('HOST', 'localhost');   // syntax error, unexpected identifier "define", expecting "," or ";"
define('USER', 'root');
```

Comment: It's a problem with the code before the first line you show us.

Answer (score 1):

With the limited information given in this post, i only see two point where the issue might hide.

1. You forgot to start your php code with a `<?php` start tag
2. You have some php code above the snippet you posted that is missing it's `;`(semicolon) on the end of it's line. Good hunting :-)

Hope this helps :-)